# Getting rid of skewness in an exploratory data analysis (EDA)

Tags: python, pandas, binning, skew

be proud to get in touch with my first question on here :)
I'm on my way to a self aducated data scientist and everyday brings another challenge. My challenge today:

I followed an example where someone used to bin the values via pandas **'cut'** function, but this doesn't get rid of the data's high skewness:

```
(-0.512, 102.466]     838
(102.466, 204.932]     33
(204.932, 307.398]     17
(409.863, 512.329]      3
(307.398, 409.863]      0
```

So I binned them with pandas **'qcut'** to get mostly even sized bins (no "visual" skewness for the distribution of bins 'value_counts'):

```
(7.854, 10.5]        184
(21.679, 39.688]     180
(-0.001, 7.854]      179
(39.688, 512.329]    176
(10.5, 21.679]       172
```

My intuition tells me, that that's not the way to handle skewed data after I read about data transformations via 'log' or 'sqrt' f.e.

Am I comparing apples with oranges here? :)